# How can I correctly yield from a stream that uses Futures/async/await?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I've encountered a weird issue where if I yield* from my provider in my flutter app, the rest of the code in the function doesn't complete.

I'm using the BLoC pattern, so my _mapEventToState function looks like this:

```
  Stream<WizardState> _mapJoiningCongregationToState(
      int identifier, int password) async* {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _subscription= (_provider.doThings(
            id: identifier, password: password))
        .listen((progress) => {
              dispatch(Event(
                  progressMessage: progress.progressText))
            }, onError: (error){
              print(error);
            }, onDone: (){
              print('done joiining');
            });
  }
```

Then in the provider/service... this is the first attempt.

```
final StreamController<Progress> _progressStream = StreamController<JoinCongregationProgress>();

 @override
  Stream<JoinCongregationProgress> doThings(
      {int id, int password}) async* {

        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
_progressStream.add(JoinCongregationProgress(progressText: "kake1..."));
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
_progressStream.add(JoinCongregationProgress(progressText: "kake5!!!..."));
yield* _progressStream.stream;
}
```

The yield statement returns, but only *after* both awaited functions have completed.  This makes complete sense to me, obviously I wouldn't expect the code to complete out of order and somehow run the yield* before waiting for the 'await's to complete.

In order to "subscribe" to the progress of this service though, I need to yield the stream back up to the caller, to write updates on the UI etc.  In my mind, this is as simple as moving the yield* to before the first await.  Like this.

```
 final StreamController<Progress> _progressStream = StreamController<JoinCongregationProgress>();

     @override
      Stream<JoinCongregationProgress> doThings(
          {int id, int password}) async* {
            yield* _progressStream.stream;
            await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
    _progressStream.add(JoinCongregationProgress(progressText: "kake1..."));
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
    _progressStream.add(JoinCongregationProgress(progressText: "kake5!!!..."));

    }
```

But, then setting breakpoints on the later _progressStream.add calls show that these never get called.  I'm stuck on this, any idea what it could be?  I know it has something to do with how I have mixed Futures and Streams.

Answer (score 1):

The `yield*` awaits the completion of the stream it returns.

In this case, you want to return a stream immediately, then asynchronously feed some data into that stream.

Is anything *else* adding events to the stream controller? If not, you should be able to just do:

```
@override
Stream<JoinCongregationProgress> doThings({int id, int password}) async* {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
    yield JoinCongregationProgress(progressText: "kake1...");
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
    yield JoinCongregationProgress(progressText: "kake5!!!...");
}
```

No stream controller is needed.

If other functions also add to the stream controller, then you do need it. You then have to splut your stream creation into an async part which updates the stream controller, and a synchronous part which returns the stream. Maybe:

```
final StreamController<Progress> _progressStream = StreamController<JoinCongregationProgress>();

@override
Stream<JoinCongregationProgress> doThings({int id, int password}) {
  () async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
    _progressStream.add(JoinCongregationProgress(progressText: "kake1..."));
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
    _progressStream.add(JoinCongregationProgress(progressText: "kake5!!!..."));
  }(); // Spin off async background task to update stream controller.
  return _progressStream.stream;
}
```

Comment: This looks good.  I think your formatting got a bit wonky towards the end of the post... I'll try this now and let you know how I get on :D

Comment: Thanks .Wonkyness removed.